# Unzipping tokenizers\punkt.zip in nltk.download('punkt')

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science

I have integrate ntlk in my python project but after installing punkt by `nltk.download('punkt')`
is is showing

> Unzipping tokenizers\punkt.zip.

I have check the nltk-data download location for confirmation but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear but try to restart your terminal and paste the following command.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
```